# removing junk folders from a war in build time

Tags: java, web-applications, build, war

I have a web application done several years back, this is done using spring and javascript.

This project we build using the Jidea, IDE.

project have several theme folders which include large amount of images.

after the build the war is so heavy because of these large unused folders and other files.

my question is, is there a method, building tool we can use to remove these junk folders at the build time??

--Rangana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use build tools such as **Maven** or **Ant**. With these, you can specify exactly what you want to include and what you want to exclude in your war file.

Example with ANT :

```
    <war destfile="dist/MyApp.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="WebContent" />
        <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
        <classes dir="build/classes">
            <exclude name="config.properties"/>
            <include name="**\*.class"/>
            <include name="**\*.xml"/>
            <include name="**\*.pdf"/>
        </classes>
        <classes file="config/staging/config.properties"/>
    </war>
```

Comment: hi thank you for the short reply, there are lot of javascript in this project, will i be able to minify javascript and css using Maven or ANT ?

Comment: Yes, there is an ant task that does this [here](http://code.google.com/p/jsmin-ant-task/) and certainly also a plugin  for maven.